# 500 Internal Errors

Tags: themes, updates, fatal-error, 500-internal-error

I am working on updating my current Eduma theme to the newest version (3.0.9.1) I currently have version 3.0.7. I am running WordPress 4.7.5.

However, while running the update I get `Update Failed: Internal Server Error` message in the middle of the installation. So I start the process, and it runs for a minute, then it simply stops working, and I am stuck in maintenance mode. So I have to manually delete the `.maintenance` file from my server.

I took a screenshot of what I see in the error.

[image]

I ran the debug mode on my WordPress Website and this is what I had

```
[31-May-2017 15:17:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /home/ccbbc/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php on line 269
[31-May-2017 15:17:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given in /home/ccbbc/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php on line 269
[31-May-2017 15:17:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/ccbbc/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-bulk-upgrader-skin.php on line 61
[31-May-2017 15:17:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  parse_url() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/ccbbc/public_html/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 497
[31-May-2017 15:17:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/ccbbc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/envato-market/inc/github.php on line 160
[31-May-2017 15:17:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to modify property of non-object in /home/ccbbc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/envato-market/inc/github.php on line 166
[31-May-2017 15:17:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/ccbbc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/thim-core/admin/class-thim-self-update.php on line 118
[31-May-2017 15:17:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/ccbbc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/envato-market/inc/items.php on line 213
[31-May-2017 15:17:27 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: themes in /home/ccbbc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/envato-market/inc/items.php on line 223
[31-May-2017 15:17:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/ccbbc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/envato-market/inc/items.php on line 235
[31-May-2017 15:17:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/ccbbc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/thim-core/admin/class-thim-auto-upgrader.php on line 217
[31-May-2017 15:17:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/ccbbc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/thim-core/admin/class-thim-auto-upgrader.php on line 189
[31-May-2017 15:17:27 UTC] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/ccbbc/public_html/wp-includes/kses.php on line 1248
[31-May-2017 15:17:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /home/ccbbc/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php on line 269
[31-May-2017 15:17:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given in /home/ccbbc/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php on line 269
[31-May-2017 15:17:46 UTC] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/ccbbc/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-automatic-upgrader-skin.php on line 79
```

Is this a problem with the theme itself and its components; or this a problem with my server? If this is on my end what should I attempt to fix this problem?

Trying to reach Eduma is a horrible experience with very little success. Moreover, this is not the first time I have run into problems updating my theme from Eduma.

Comment: I would suggest to try the following. Login via an FTP and download your current theme content then download a fresh copy of Wordpress and replace your current Wordpress files on your server this will rule out any Wordpress corrupted file next manually upload your theme update by downloading it from the source of purchase and deleting the current theme folder then if this all works you have both fresh installs. If that does not work replace your theme with the backup your downloaded and contact the theme maker.

Comment: The OP says that he is running 4.7.5, which is latest version. If there is a possibility of WP core code, then a reinstall of the latest WP from the Admin Update page will take care of that problem. But, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your theme is using deprecated PHP code functions, and those are causing the errors.

Since the theme author is (at best) unresponsive, I'd suggest moving to a different theme.

Comment: Right, I wish I could; we have recently purchase it and I don't know if I can make the case to drop it just yet. But I was able to get a hold of tech support and figure it out. I am still not sure as to what the extent of the problem was; just ran a complete reinstall of the theme itself.